# zookeeper+kerberos:server not found in kerberos database (7) - unknown_server

Tags: hadoop, hbase, kerberos

I do hbase+kerberos for safety verification on linux RHEL7,There one error show when i use zookeeper client server by command "zkCli.sh -server master":

......
mechanism level server not found in kerberos database (7) - unknown_server......

[Here is Detail logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VQOQ.png)

Hbase Hmaster and RegionServer can not work by this error.
I have checked all my kerberos and zookeeper configs,i do not know why this error occur.

Comment: (1).hosts has added.

Comment: (2).add jvmflags:Dsun.net.spi.nameService.provider = dns,sun  can not resolve this error.

Comment: links get broken, please edit your post and add the logs to your question.

Comment: Kerberos expects *canonical DNS names* by default (can be spoofed via `/etc/hosts`, can be relaxed with some Krb config) -- what happens when you `nslookup master` then reverse-lookup the IP given?

Comment: Did you properly specify the rules that Kerberos must use to map a server to a realm, in `/etc/krb5.conf`? It's usually based on DNS domain, but since `master` has no domain you have to define per-server rules

Comment: Recommended reading: the GitBook _Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate_, sections "Errors to fear" and "Low-level secrets" (for debug trace flags)

Comment: @Samson Scharfrichter Thanks for uper answer,It is ok when i run command nslookup master.I think the krb5.conf is ok,because run kinit for the tgt successful.

Comment: `kinit` creates a TGT as proof of your authentication. But the ZK client lib needs to create a **service ticket** valid for a **specific ZK server** -- that's where DNS is involved *(to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks and so on)*